# New XML file when change a AXML file xamarain for Android, why?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

I need change a AXML file in an old Xamarin.Android APP, I'm not an expert, I have just this one APP and I don't change it in long time. When I changed the AXML file, Visual Sutdio created a new XML file equals to my AXML file, now the two of them are in my project. I couldn't find anything about having the two files in project. Should I keep the two files in project? Any explanation about it would help, thanks in advance.

[image: Solution Explorer]